# I am getting some errors which is Test1.rb:66:in `syear': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

This is the code for counting the number of final year student. I am also having trouble to repeat the all the following student in the class.

This program counts the number of final year students in the class

```
def main

puts "Enter total number of students in the class:"
# get input from user (int)
x = gets.chomp.to_i

# call syear(    ) function
r = syear(x)

# Write a puts statement to display the number of final year students in the class
# eg: There are 4 final year students in the class
puts "There are " + r.to_s + " final year students in the class."

end
```

## This function receives the total number of students in the class as

parameter and returns the number of final year students back to the call statement

```
  def syear(a)
  count = 1
  sem = 0


# Repeat all the following for every student in the class
begin

puts "Input semester (1-6):"
# get user to input the semester (int) of each student 

sem = gets.chomp.to_i

# Display the student's status as either "Year 1 Student", "Year 2 Student" 
# or "Final Year Student" base on the following scheme: 
# Semester 1 or 2 - First year student, Semester 3 or 4 - Second year 
student, 
# Semester 5 to 6 - Final year student.
if (sem == 1 | 2)
types = "Year 1 Students"
else 
    if ( sem == 3 | 4 )

    types = "Year 2 Students"

    else 
        if (sem == 5 & 6 )
        types = "Final Year Students"

     end


    end





     # This function will also count and return the number of final year student    in the class (Hints: use a variable to perform the counting)
     if (types == "Final Year Students")

   numofstudents +=1

  end 
  count +=1
  end while (count < a)

  numofstudents
  end
  end

  main
```

Comment: r = syear() is the line error

Comment: And i am having trouble to repeat all the following student

Comment: i post in the answer section

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into your question and format your code properly. Posting parts of the questions into an answer is not helpful – especially because it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: alright sorry i am still a beginner on programming. I had already edited and format the question

Comment: @AjiAyi : I don't see any error message in your question. And, post the complete program, to the extent it is necessary to discuss the problem. Right now, you have posted two snippets, where we can't see how they are related. Finally, what's the point of the isolated `class` statement inside the body of your `main` method? You should get a syntax error from this.

Comment: You don't set `numofstudents` to any starting value (so it will start as `nil`). Should it start at 0? Add `numofstudents = 0` at the top.

Comment: @user1934428 ah...sorry the class is actually part of the comment

Comment: @simonwo ohhh...i think i did not put that. Thanks another question is how to repeat all the following for every student?

Comment: `if(sem == 1 | 2)` will only be true if `sem` is `3`. There are 2 reasons for this 1) `|` has a higher precedence than `==` so this becomes `sem == (1 | 2)` and 2) `Integer#|` is a bitwise OR so this essentially follows as (using bitwise notation) `sem == ( 01 | 10)`, then `sem == (11)`, which is `sem == 3`. Logical OR in ruby is `||` and this would need to change to `sem == 1 || sem == 2` because `sem == 1 || 2` would always be true because it is interpreted as `(sem == 1) || true` since 2 is truthy.

Comment: Likewise `5 & 6` == `4` because `&` is a bitwise AND so `101 & 110 == 100` which is 4. Logical AND in ruby is `&&`

Comment: @AjiAyi : Another, unrelated, point: Why do you use a `begin` if you don't do a `rescue`?

Comment: @engineersmnky I see thanks for telling me that I think I get it now.